# Change page without changing location.path or location.url

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible for AngularJS to change your page without changing your location path/url?

Like for instance I have a table page that has the path/url `<host>/<app>/table` and when I click on the entry in the table, it goes to an element detail page but the path/url stays the same (since this operation is confined anyway to the `/table` path) ?

Answer (score 0):

you can always use ng-include to load a template on a specific part of your page.
that would change the content of that part without changing the url of the page.